# Avoiding duplicate provisioning when defining multiple Vagrant VMs

Tags: vagrant, provisioning, vagrant-provision

### The Question

I'm trying to make provisioning multiple copies of essentially the same vagrant VM (only differing in networking) faster. The issue I'm having is that vagrant seems to perform the provisioning step on each machine, sequentially.

The reason I want to save time here is because I'm using vagrant as part of a test harness, so I need to minimize the time needed to run tests.

For example, consider the following Vagrantfile:

```ruby
N_HOSTS = 3
$script = <<SCRIPT
    sudo apt-get -y update
SCRIPT

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  (1..N_HOSTS).each do |i|
    config.vm.define "host#{i}" do |sc|
      sc.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
      sc.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.#{10 + i}"
      sc.vm.hostname = "host#{i}"
    end
  end

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $script
end
```

It's relatively simple. All it does is `apt-get update`, yet `vagrant up` takes 2m15s on an otherwise idle desktop.

### Potential Solutions

1. Provisioning the machines in parallel. [Currently unanswered on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45823630/vagrant-multi-machine-parallel-start).
2. Provisioning the first machine, packing it to a box, and starting hosts 2..N from the freshly packed box. I'm new to Vagrant so it's unclear to me how to do this, and whether it's the best way to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 1):

You can start your VMs in parallel using `xargs`,  which supports parallel command execution with the key `-P <max-procs>` (for your Vagrantfile):

```
seq 1 N | xargs -PN -I {} vagrant up host{}
```

So if you want to start three VMs simultaneously it is:

```
seq 1 3 | xargs -P3 -I {} vagrant up host{}
```

Comment: Thank you, this definitely makes `up` faster. However we still have the duplicate provisioning issue.