# Include multiple Vagrantfiles in a single do config block for multi machine setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

## TL;DR

The Vagrant docs recomment a single `do |config|` block for defining multiple machines. I can't make this work when outsourcing every box to a single partial Vagrantfile config, that got included. It seem to work with multiple config blocks, but parallel provisioning doesn't work using VirtualBox.

EDIT: [Parallel execution doesn't seem to work on VirtualBox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48177184/3276634)

### Questions:

1. Are there any disadvantages when having multiple `do |config|` blocks for multiple machines?
2. If yes: How can I include multile Vagrantfile partial files with access to the global parent `config` object?

## Detailled explanation and background

I'm working on a Vagrantfile that should create multiple machines with different configurations. To avoid messing up the single Vagrantfile, I want a modular design like this:

```
Vagrantfile
vagrant
  -- Vagrantfile.service1
  -- Vagrantfile.service2
```

[The Vagrant documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/multi-machine/) uses a single `config` block for defining multiple machines inside. But all machines are provided in the same Vagrantfile. To keep modular, separated files I only found [this repo](https://github.com/erran-r7/multiple_vagrantfiles), where all partial configs got included *outside* the `config` block, so there is a single `config` block in every machine config. On the vagrant docs example, it would looks like this:

```
# File Vagrantfile-service1
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "apache"
end

# File Vagrantfile-service2
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "mysql"
end
```

But according to the github example, I need to include those files in the base `Vagrantfile` like this:

```
path1 = "vagrant/Vagrantfile.service1"
load File.expand_path(path1)  if File.exists?(path1)

path2 = "vagrant/Vagrantfile.service2"
load File.expand_path(path2)  if File.exists?(path2)
```

As you can see, this works only with multiple `do |config|` sections. The base Vagrantfile doesn't contain any. Since the vagrant docs say:

> And importantly, you can continue to use the config object as well.

## What I already tried

I tried to define a config block in the Vagrantfile and include my partial files:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  path1 = "vagrant/Vagrantfile.service1"
  load File.expand_path(path1)  if File.exists?(path1)
  # ...
end
```

The idea was to use `config` object in `vagrant/Vagrantfile.service1` so that this file only contains

```
config.vm.define "web" do |web|
  web.vm.box = "apache"
end
```

That fits the vagrant docs. But it doesn't work. Altough I'm not very familar with Ruby, it seems that `config` must be a global variable in the base `Vagrantfile`. So I tried

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |$config|
  path1 = "vagrant/Vagrantfile.service1"
  load File.expand_path(path1)  if File.exists?(path1)
  # ...
end
```

notice the `$config` to make it global, which result in this error:

```
Vagrantfile:21: formal argument cannot be a global variable
grant.configure(2) do |$config|
                              ^
```

I also tried the following without success:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |_config|
  $config = _config
  # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `load` try using `eval` to use parent `Vagrantfile` `config` in `vagrant/Vagrantfile.service1`.

```
if File.exist?('vagrant/Vagrantfile.service1'))
    eval(IO.read('vagrant/Vagrantfile.service1')), binding)
end
```